# How do I remove windows features from disk in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, dism

[This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/) says that one can use DISM /Remove to remove features from disk, changing the status to "Disabled with Payload Removed" instead of just "Disabled." When I tried, it said:

```
C:\Windows\system32>dism /Online /Disable-Feature /featurename:OEMHelpCustomization /Remove

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385

Image Version: 6.1.7601.18489


Error: 87

The remove option is not recognized in this context.
```

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824822.aspx#BKMK_remove) says you can only do it on windows 8. Is there a way on Windows 7?  (I have an up-to-date Windows 7 Professional according to Windows Update.)

I'm trying to reduce the size of the large winsxs directory.  (I already disabled hybrid sleep, removing the hiberfil.sys file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is called [Features on Demand](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/11/20/features-on-demand-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) and is **only available since Windows 8**. This **doesn't work in Windows 7**. To use it you must upgrade to Windows 8 or 8.1